# How to import Jupyter notebook without automatically running it?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When looking at a solution to import an IPython file from another, I found the solution of:

```
import import_ipynb
from Genetic_Algorithm_Library_Code import ga
```

However, when I run the code, the program from the other file starts running immediately. Is it possible to only import functions and run them when I want on the second file?

Edit:

Problem solved: Used nbimporter instead.

```
import nbimporter
import gapro as gapro
```

Comment: if you have solved the problem it might help someone in the future to post the answer with some explanation.